# Google Play Game service and 2 app versions

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have an app where I want to integrate Google Play Games (GPG), but there is a free and a pay version.  The free version's package is xx1.xx2.xx3.free where as the paid version is xx1.xx2.xx3, how can I set up GPG such that people on the free version and the paid version will be able to play against each other?  Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link multiple apps to the same game in the "Linked App" Section. That would do the trick for you.

[image]